# ClassNotFoundException BootstrapApplication, android?

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception

Whenever I am trying to run my app I get this error.

I have even disabled Instatn run in the studio

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.vfirst.supermax-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.vfirst.supermax-1/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:578)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4828)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1454)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5568)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.vfirst.supermax-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.vfirst.supermax-1/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:982)
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:573)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4828) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:154) 
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

Comment: clean your project and reinstall app

Comment: go to build path and check your jar file libary

Comment: Did you find a solution?  I am facing a similar problem.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky it is because of the play services if you are using them, seperate them as to which play service is needed for your app

Comment: @WISHY Right, but for example **GooglePlayServicesUtil** extends from **zze.class**, which is an obfuscated class that isn't put on the classpath.  Hence these types of errors when adding standalone jar files for Play Services.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the Instant Run option in Android Studio. Instructions are in the [Android Studio Instant Run documentation.](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/instant-run)

Instant Run tries to do hot swapping of your code; this causes the application class to be moved.

To disable Instant Run Go to

`File --> 
      Settings--> 
           Build,
           Execution,
           Deployment -->
                        Instant Run --->
                        uncheck "Enable instant run"`

Comment: This is good suggestion as the APK file doesn't work on older devices when did instance